# Node keeps reverting back to older version

Tags: node.js

Every time I restart vagrant in my console it will ask me my login details and then say `Now using node v7.10.0 (npm v4.2.0)`. When I do `run nvm install node` I get

`v13.11.0 is already installed.
Now using node v13.11.0 (npm v6.13.7)`

... but then I exit and come back and it's v7.10.0 again. This is causing problems with my rails apps when I try to create them because it says the latest version isn't installed, and then I have to install Yarn and it won't find it. A whole mess, not sure what to do.

Answer (score 26):

You can run the following command to set `v13.11.0` as default

```
nvm alias default v13.11.0
```

This works for me.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason this doesn't work for me. As soon as I exit and relog it reverts to 7.10.0

Comment: `nvm ls` to list all installed version of node and `nvm current` to log default version

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't works for you. How are you checking the version of node.

Comment: Tried the above as well, still resetting every time I restart  vagrant. I checked in the ways you listed and I check with node -v each time I log in

Comment: It's saying my default is 13.11.0 but it always sets my current node back to 7.10.0

Comment: It's saying default is 13.11.0, So how can you say that your current node version is 7.10.0 Is `node -v` show you `v7.10.0`

Comment: Yes correct. Every time I restart it tells me I'm using `v7.10.0`, and `node -v` shows me that too. And when I type `nvm ls` it shows the arrow is on `v7.10.0` but it says my default and stable are `v13.11.0`

Comment: After running the command, Plz close the terminal and reopen it and run `node -v`

Comment: Just did that, still showing `v7.10.0` when I log in and when I enter `node -v`

Comment: `nvm use v13.11.0` and `node -v`

Comment: That does work as a temporary fix, but when I restart vagrant it reverts every single time

Comment: Didn't work for me on Mac Terminal, node -v always shows older version of node; even after running above command

Comment: @vikramvi After running the command, Plz close the terminal and reopen it and run node -v Hope this solv your poblm.

Comment: No, the issue was entry in .bash_profile; all the entries related to NVM should be in the bottom

Answer (score 6):

Maybe try to switch the Node version.
Do `nvm ls` Which would give you a list of installed NodeJS versions.
Then do `nvm use v13.11.0`
Then set it to default using: `nvm alias default 13.11.0`

Answer (score 3):

switch using `nvm use 17`
set as default with `nvm alias default 17`

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was trying to upgrade from v16 to v20 using nvm. No matter what I did, new sessions always reverted back to v16. I had completely removed NodeJS from the system using nvm and my package manager AND removed nvm completely and the terminal STILL said I had it installed as v16. So it was installed somewhere else. I was pretty sure I had installed v16 with nvm, but turns out I was wrong.

I did a `which node` in terminal and it told me the binaries were in `~/.volta/bin/node`. And that's when I remembered that I had used Volta to manage my NodeJS and not nvm.

Perhaps this is what some of you may be experiencing: did it once and forgot about how you did it!

See https://volta.sh. It is quite easy to use.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It kept reverting back everytime I would open a new instance of a terminal.
I had to just delete all the other versions to get it working in the end
use this command to uninstall the other node versions

```
nvm ls    
nvm uninstall [X.Y.Z]
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally it should set the LTS version with:

```
nvm alias default node
```

But if you have a different version in your .nvmrc file it can cause reverting back to the old version.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled a lot with that. Finally I `open ~/.zshrc` and found `export PATH` with the version that always returns. So if anything helps check that out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).